# Can tensorflow Saver be used in different graphs with the same structure

Tags: python, tensorflow

The network structure has already been loaded into the default global graph. I want to create another graph with the same structure and load checkpoints into this graph.

If the code is like this, it will throw error: ***ValueError: No variables to save*** in the last line. However, the second line works fine. Why? Does `GraphDef` returned by `as_graph_def()` contains variable definition/name?

```
inference_graph_def = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    tf.import_graph_def(inference_graph_def)
    saver1 = tf.train.Saver()
```

If the code like this, it will throw error ***Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: The name 'save/Const:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist*** in last line. Howerver, it works fine with the 3rd line removed.

```
inference_graph_def = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    tf.import_graph_def(inference_graph_def)    
    with session.Session() as sess:        
        saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_path)
```

So, does this mean Saver cannot work in different graphs even though they have the same structure?

Any help would be appreciated~

Comment: The Saver decides which Variables to save when it is constructed. If there's no graph at that point, it won't see any Variables to save. Maybe just construct the Saver after the graph has been loaded?

Comment: As I said, the network structure has already been loaded into the default global graph and I use `tf.import_graph_def` to load the graphDef to the current graph.

Comment: Ah, I see. Did not read the question carefully enough. So in the first case, collections are not saved with the GraphDef (in this case the global variables collection). [MetaGraphs do have that information](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/meta_graph), or you could go right to SavedModel format. In the second case there's a default prefix applied to operations (see the `name` argument to `import_graph_def`), so you'd need to either remove that or do an explicit mapping.

Comment: @AllenLavoie Thanks for your reply. You really helped me with my confusion.  I followed your suggestion to remove the default prefix by using `tf.import_graph_def(graph_def=inference_graph_def,name='') `, but the error still exists. Did I miss anything? Would you mind giving a more detailed explanation about how Saver uses information  from graph and the explicit mapping? Much Appreciation.

Comment: Ah, right, that addresses the naming issue, but you'd need to explicitly specify the variables when constructing the second Saver (or re-use the original Saver which already has the Variable names in mind). I've added an answer that avoids this complexity by using MetaGraphs instead of GraphDefs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of using a `MetaGraphDef`, which unlike `GraphDef` saves variable collections, to initialize a new graph using a previously saved graph.

```
import tensorflow as tf

CHECKPOINT_PATH = "/tmp/first_graph_checkpoint"
with tf.Graph().as_default():
  some_variable = tf.get_variable(
    name="some_variable",
    shape=[2],
    dtype=tf.float32)
  init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
  first_meta_graph = tf.train.export_meta_graph()
  first_graph_saver = tf.train.Saver()
  with tf.Session() as session:
    init_op.run()
    print("Initialized value in first graph", some_variable.eval())
    first_graph_saver.save(
        sess=session,
        save_path=CHECKPOINT_PATH)

with tf.Graph().as_default():
  tf.train.import_meta_graph(first_meta_graph)
  second_graph_saver = tf.train.Saver()
  with tf.Session() as session:
    second_graph_saver.restore(
      sess=session,
      save_path=CHECKPOINT_PATH)
    print("Variable value after restore", tf.global_variables()[0].eval())
```

Prints something like:

```
Initialized value in first graph [-0.98926258 -0.09709156]
Variable value after restore [-0.98926258 -0.09709156]
```

Note that the checkpoint is still important! Loading the `MetaGraph` does not restore the values of `Variables` (it doesn't contain those values), just the bookkeeping which tracks their existence (collections). [SavedModel format](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model) addresses this, bundling `MetaGraph`s with checkpoints and other metadata for running them.

Edit: By popular demand, here's an example of doing the same thing with a `GraphDef`. I don't recommend it. Since none of the collections are restored when the `GraphDef` is loaded, we have to manually specify the `Variables` we want the `Saver` to restore; the "import/" default naming scheme is easy enough to fix with a `name=''` argument to `import_graph_def`, but removing it isn't super helpful since you'd need to manually fill in the variables collection if you wanted the `Saver` to work "automatically". Instead I've chosen to specify a mapping manually when creating the `Saver`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

CHECKPOINT_PATH = "/tmp/first_graph_checkpoint"
with tf.Graph().as_default():
  some_variable = tf.get_variable(
    name="some_variable",
    shape=[2],
    dtype=tf.float32)
  init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
  first_graph_def = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()
  first_graph_saver = tf.train.Saver()
  with tf.Session() as session:
    init_op.run()
    print("Initialized value in first graph", some_variable.eval())
    first_graph_saver.save(
        sess=session,
        save_path=CHECKPOINT_PATH)

with tf.Graph().as_default():
  tf.import_graph_def(first_graph_def)
  variable_to_restore = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(
      "import/some_variable:0")
  second_graph_saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list={
      "some_variable": variable_to_restore
  })
  with tf.Session() as session:
    second_graph_saver.restore(
      sess=session,
      save_path=CHECKPOINT_PATH)
    print("Variable value after restore", variable_to_restore.eval())
```

Comment: Yes, I get your point! I've tried myself and it works. You are right, `export_meta_graph` is a simpler way to re-use graph but I am still curious about that complex way using explicit mapping. Could you please give an example too?

Comment: Sure, easy enough.

Comment: That's quite clear! Thanks again for your kind help~